# django rest not showing one of the endpoints in API root

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

[image][image]One of the viewsets named 'wallet' is not showing in the main API page. I checked the routers registered in the urls, but I'm not finding the issue.

SiteWallet model:

```
class SiteWallet(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(SiteUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='SiteWallet')
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=40, decimal_places=2, default=0 , blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Wallet'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Wallets'


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.owner} : {self.balance}$"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("Wallet_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        self.save()
        WalletTransaction.objects.create_deposit_transaction(self, amount)

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.withdraw_valid(amount):
            self.balance -= amount
            self.save()
            WalletTransaction.objects.create_withdraw_transaction(self, amount)
        else:
            raise Exception("Not enough $")

    def withdraw_valid(self, amount):
        if self.balance >= amount:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

WalletSerializer:

```
class WalletSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SiteWallet
        fields = ['balance']
```

WalletViewSet:

```
class WalletViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin
                    ,viewsets.GenericViewSet):
"""endpoint for viewing the balance of wallet or charging it"""
    serializer_class = WalletSerializer
    permission_classes =[IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    queryset = SiteWallet.objects.all()

    @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
    def charge_account(self, request):
        wallet = self.get_object()
        wallet.deposit(request.data['amount'])
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
    def withdraw(self, request):
        wallet = self.get_object()
        wallet.withdraw(request.data['amount'])
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and the app's urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"Users", SiteUserViewSet, basename="Site Users")
router.register(r"Wallet", WalletViewSet, basename="wallets")
router.register(r"Bank accounts", BankAccountViewSet, basename="bank account")
router.register(r"Wallet transaction", WalletTransactionViewSet, basename='wallet transaction')

urlpatterns =[
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout')
] + router.urls
```

I'm new to Django, if there's any part of the code that's badly written or needs refactoring, I would appreciate the tip.

Comment: Post your error message.